# What is the design pattern in this code?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, reflection, factory

Say I have a singleton-ish, factory-ish, reflection-ish class that receives some input, and spits back a new instance of a concrete implementation of some interface.  What kind of design is this? Is there a better way to do what I want?

Here's some code to illustrate the point:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

// static factory class
public static class ArticleFactory 
{
    // given an SKU, store the Type object for an IArticle object
    private static Dictionary<string, Type> articleRegistry = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

    // allow public registration of SKU-to-Type object relationships
    public static bool Register(string sku, Type typeInfo)
    {
        if(!articleRegistry.ContainsKey(sku)) 
        {
            articleRegistry.Add(sku, typeInfo);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // given a SKU, give me an instance of the related IArticle object
    public static IArticle NewArticle(string sku)
    {
        if(articleRegistry.ContainsKey(sku))
        {
            // use reflection to invoke the default constructor
            return articleRegistry[sku].GetConstructor(Types.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null) as IArticle;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

// example concrete-implementation of an IArticle
public class Jeans : IArticle 
{
    public decimal GetPrice() {  return SomeDecimal(); }
}

// WHERE DO I CALL THIS LINE? 
ArticleFactory.Register("0929-291", typeof(Jeans)); 

// Later on, if another group needs to write the class for Snowboards, 
// how can they self-register their class, without changing any "Main()"
// or "Page_Init()" function?
```

Comment: I believe that's the *Refactleton* pattern. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've already identified the pattern.  It's the [Factory Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).  Or rather, a somewhat half-baked implementation of one.  A slightly better approach would be to first make it an interface:

```
public interface IArticleFactory
{
    IArticle CreateArticle(string sku);
}
```

Then implement the factory without any Reflection at all:

```
public class MyArticleFactory
{
    private Dictionary<string, Func<IArticle>> instantiators =
        new Dictionary<string, Func<Iarticle>>();

    public MyArticleFactory()
    {
        Register("Jeans", () => new Jeans());
        Register("Shirt", () => new Shirt());
        // etc.
    }

    public IArticle CreateArticle(string sku)
    {
        Func<IArticle> instantiator;
        if (creators.TryGetValue(sku, out instantiator))
            return instantiator();
        throw new UnknownSkuException(sku);
    }

    protected void Register(string sku, Func<IArticle> instantiator)
    {
        creators.Add(sku, instantiator);
    }
}
```

A few important differences:

- Registration isn't public, nor should it be.  Registration usually either resides in a configuration file somewhere or is private.
- Does not require the `IArticle` concrete types to have a default parameterless constructor.  This can easily register articles with parameterized constructors (as long as it knows what parameters to use).
- Throws an exception on duplicate registrations.  I don't like the idea of simply returning `false`; if you try to register the same factory method twice, that ought to be considered a bug.
- It's not static.  You can replace this factory with a different factory.  You can unit-test it.

Of course, an even better approach would just be to use any of the myriad of existing .NET Dependency Injection/Inversion of Control Frameworks, such as [Ninject](http://ninject.org/) or [AutoFac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/).

Comment: Thanks - while all the answers point in the same general direction (IoC), you gave me an idea of how to proceed.  SO rocks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it has a "name" as such, but it looks like some kind of manual service resolver. The problem I can see (from experience, sadly) is that it is inflexible in real terms, in that:

- the registration only has a single configuration
- it is hard to unit test

Personally I'd look at an IoC container if I was doing this in a new system; the IoC can handle this relationship, and provide a lot more capabilities for free (lifetimes, enrichment, extra setup, etc), and solve many associated problems.

BTW, it may be easier to:

```
return Activator.CreateInstance(articleRegistry[sku]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're doing here is basically Dependency Injection (or Inversion of Control is what the cool kids call it). Have a look at these links:

Explanation from Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection

Two DI .Net frameworks:

StructureMap: http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/QuickStart.htm

Castle Windsor: http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html

Comment: Note: DI and IoC are two very different concepts.  They just happen to be combined in a number of DI frameworks.

Comment: Dependency Injection sounds so much cooler than Inversion of Control ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's just a factory pattern that happens to use reflection in its implementation.  Rather than using reflection, though, it would probably be more efficient to simply put instances of factory classes directly in the dictionary, though this might require some boilerplate code.